# Flutter - QR Code generated when user signs up and links to their profile

Tags: flutter, profile

I am currently developing an application which has a profile page for patients to input their details etc. using flutter

I am wondering if anyone can help me or give me some direction on how to generate a qr code that specifically links to their profile once a user signs up. I have qr scanner built into the app and would like to be able to scan the qr code on someone elses phone and bring up their profile.

I can't seem to find anything around what I want or it's just because typing qr code into google comes up with guides on how to create a scanner only.

Comment: here you go https://pub.dev/packages/qr

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use the QR Flutter package here to generate the qr code. https://pub.dev/packages/qr_flutter

you will need to come up with String that will be used to reference the profile... either a url or a profile id. then pass that to QrImage:

```
QrImage(
  data: "your_string_here",
  version: QrVersions.auto,
  size: 200.0,
),
```